# How to download different html canvas after drawing on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, async-await, html5-canvas

I'm working on an **nft-art-generator app**, the app generate multiple and **differnte** html canvas (as image).
Each canvas is a combination of 3 images, in other words, 3 images should be drawn in each canvas and after drawing on canvas i download it.

The Problem is that when i check the downloaded canvas, i get the same canvas. To be more precise I get the last generated canvas has been downloaded multiple time, it's like all canvas generated before are gone.

**I think that happened because something in my code is running asynchronously.**

## Here is my React.js Code

```js
const generateCollection = async()=>{

//In this exemple i want to generate 2 canvas only!!
  for(var k = 1; k <= 2; k++){
    drawLayer(data, k)
   }
  
}
  
const drawLayer = (data, index)=>{
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let sources = {};
  //Get some random images url
  const objURLs = getImagesURLs(data, index);
  
  objURLs.forEach((url,i)=>{
    const key = `image${i+1}`;
    Object.assign(sources, {[key]: url})
  })
  
  loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    objURLs.forEach((url,i)=>{
      if (Boolean(url)) {
        context.drawImage(images[`image${i+1}`], 0, 0, 230, 230)
      }
    })
  });
  
  setTimeout(()=> download(canvas.current, index), 1000);
  
}

const loadImages = (sources, callback)=> {
  var images = {};
  var loadedImages = 0;
  var numImages = 0;
  // get num of sources
  for(var src in sources) {
    numImages++;
  }
  for(var src in sources) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() {
      if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
        console.log("!!  ", images )
          callback(images);
      }
    };
    images[src].src = sources[src];
  }
}

const download = (canvas, index)=>{
  console.log("Download: ", canvas)
  var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = `img_${index}.png`;
  link.href = url;
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<canvas 
  id="myCanvas"
  ref={canvas}
  width={230}
  height={230}
/>

<Button onClick={()=>generateCollection()} ><Button>
```

### Here is a live demo code based on

https://jsfiddle.net/vprdhomf/1/

```
I will appreciate any help, or suggestion!!
```

Comment: (1) loading images is asynchronous, so `callback` is called asynchronously. (2) if all canvas combinations have been completed in less than a second, the `setTimeout` call to `download` only sees the canvas in its final state - either wait for each download before creating the next download, or use multiple canvas elements. (3) If the images are loaded across domains, and the server doesn't allow [cross domain requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin), `canvas.toDataURL` throws an exception. Fixing the fiddle appears impossible because of this.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer was clear and very helpful!!. What I did is waiting for each download before creating the next download. The **setTimeout** function was unuseful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lift from question comment:

1. Loading images is asynchronous, so `callback` is called asynchronously.
2. If all canvas combinations (of different sets of multiple images) have been completed in less than a second, the `setTimeout` call to `download` only sees the canvas in its final state. To resolve this you can either

   - Wait for each download to be initiated before creating the next download, or
   - Use multiple canvas elements, or perhaps
   - Store data URLs in an array for each canvas combination for downloading later.
3. If the images are loaded across domains, and the server doesn't allow [cross domain requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin), `canvas.toDataURL` throws a [security exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#exceptions). Fixing the fiddle using the URLs provided in it became impossible because of this.